# Do C compilers generally optimize out initialized global data?

Tags: variables, optimization, initialization, global

I am decompiling Super Smash Bros. for the Nintendo 64. It released in 1999 and was built with a rather inefficient compiler (IDO 7.1) that is missing certain features, for one. My goals include making the code as flexible as possible right out of the box.

One hurdle I've got to overcome is initializing an array that needs to contain various commands with different bitfields for a script; these are parsed in order and all of them need to be present. A union would work here if it weren't for the fact that IDO does not support designated initializers; only the first member of the union can be set.

My next best bet is to initialize the commands one-by-one, but the problem with that is that only the first command in the script would be referenced. Generally speaking, do compilers tend to discard initialized data that is "not used"? IDO more than likely would not, but I wonder if any gymnastics is necessary to keep the unreferenced data.

If all else fails, I'd have to make it an array of unsigned integers and cram everything into it in binary format and use a macro to do the bitshifting.

```
// ColAnim Script 0 is NULL

// 0x8012CA90 - ColAnim Script 1 (only Col1_Ev0 referenced)
caColorEventSetRGBA     caColorEvents_Col1_Ev0 = { caColorEvent_Kind_SetColor1, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x30 };
caColorEventDefault     caColorEvents_Col1_Ev1 = { caColorEvent_Kind_Wait, 65535 };
caColorEventGoto        caColorEvents_Col1_Ev2 = { caColorEvent_Kind_Goto, &caColorEvents_Col1_Ev0 };

// 0x8012CAA4 - ColAnim Script 2 (only Col2_Ev0 referenced)
caColorEventDefault     caColorEvents_Col2_Ev0 = { caColorEvent_Kind_ToggleColorOff };
caColorEventDefault     caColorEvents_Col2_Ev1 = { caColorEvent_Kind_End };

// 0x8012CAAC - ColAnim Script 3 (only Col3_Ev0 referenced)
caColorEventSetRGBA     caColorEvents_Col3_Ev0 = { caColorEvent_Kind_SetColor1, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x82 };
caColorEventBlendRGBA   caColorEvents_Col3_Ev1 = { caColorEvent_Kind_BlendColor1, 3, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x32 };
caColorEventDefault     caColorEvents_Col3_Ev2 = { caColorEvent_Kind_Wait, 3 };
caColorEventDefault     caColorEvents_Col3_Ev3 = { caColorEvent_Kind_ToggleColorOff };
caColorEventDefault     caColorEvents_Col3_Ev4 = { caColorEvent_Kind_Wait, 1 };
caColorEventGoto        caColorEvents_Col3_Ev5 = { caColorEvent_Kind_Goto, &caColorEvents_Col3_Ev0 };
```

Comment: It seems you want to use the _commands_ in a _script_ like an array; in this case, you have to worry not only about noninitial commands being discarded, but also about them being stored nonconsecutively.